# Каскадное подключение второго контроллера(Подсистема прерываний)

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер, микроконтроллеры, процессор

Я изучаю организацию прерываний в IBM PC с использованием контроллера прерываний. При нажатии клавишей мыши должен меняться: 0-ой бит(таймер), 2-ой бит (каскадное подключение второго контроллера) и 12-ый бит (мышь). На моём компьютере с процессором Intel Pentium при нажатии клавиши не меняется 2-ой бит. От чего это может зависеть ?

```
  #include <dos.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print(char* str, int x, int y, unsigned char color);
void binstring(unsigned char temp, char *str);
void get_reg();

void interrupt intNewIRQ0();
void interrupt intNewIRQ1();
void interrupt intNewIRQ2();
void interrupt intNewIRQ3();
void interrupt intNewIRQ4();
void interrupt intNewIRQ5();
void interrupt intNewIRQ6();
void interrupt intNewIRQ7();
void interrupt intNewIRQ8();
void interrupt intNewIRQ9();
void interrupt intNewIRQ10();
void interrupt intNewIRQ11();
void interrupt intNewIRQ12();
void interrupt intNewIRQ13();
void interrupt intNewIRQ14();
void interrupt intNewIRQ15();
void interrupt (*intOldIRQ0)();
void interrupt (*intOldIRQ1)();
void interrupt (*intOldIRQ2)();
void interrupt (*intOldIRQ3)();
void interrupt (*intOldIRQ4)();
void interrupt (*intOldIRQ5)();
void interrupt (*intOldIRQ6)();
void interrupt (*intOldIRQ7)();
void interrupt (*intOldIRQ8)();
void interrupt (*intOldIRQ9)();
void interrupt (*intOldIRQ10)();
void interrupt (*intOldIRQ11)();
void interrupt (*intOldIRQ12)();
void interrupt (*intOldIRQ13)();
void interrupt (*intOldIRQ14)();
void interrupt (*intOldIRQ15)();
void resetint();

unsigned char color = 0x4E;
unsigned char colornumber = 0;

void main()
{       
    unsigned char value;

    intOldIRQ0 = getvect(0x08);     // IRQ0 SYSTEM CLOCK(timer (55ms intervals, 18.2 per second))
    intOldIRQ1 = getvect(0x09);     // IRQ1 KEYBOARD
    intOldIRQ2 = getvect(0x0A);     // IRQ2 CASCADE(slave 8259 or EGA/VGA vertical retrace)
    intOldIRQ3 = getvect(0x0B);     // IRQ3 COM2 or COM4 service required
    intOldIRQ4 = getvect(0x0C);     // IRQ4 COM1 or COM3 service required
    intOldIRQ5 = getvect(0x0D);     // IRQ5 fixed disk or data request from LPT2
    intOldIRQ6 = getvect(0x0E);     // IRQ6 FLOPPY DISK DRIVE
    intOldIRQ7 = getvect(0x0F);     // IRQ7 PRINTER(data request from LPT1)

    intOldIRQ8 = getvect(0x70);     // IRQ8  real time clock
    intOldIRQ9 = getvect(0x71);     // IRQ9  software redirected to IRQ2
    intOldIRQ10 = getvect(0x72);    // IRQ10 reserved
    intOldIRQ11 = getvect(0x73);    // IRQ11 reserved
    intOldIRQ12 = getvect(0x74);    // IRQ12 mouse interrupt
    intOldIRQ13 = getvect(0x75);    // IRQ13 numeric coprocessor error
    intOldIRQ14 = getvect(0x76);    // IRQ14 fixed disk controller
    intOldIRQ15 = getvect(0x77);    // IRQ15 reserved

    setvect(0xB8, intNewIRQ0);
    setvect(0xB9, intNewIRQ1);
    setvect(0xBA, intNewIRQ2);
    setvect(0xBB, intNewIRQ3);
    setvect(0xBC, intNewIRQ4);
    setvect(0xBD, intNewIRQ5);
    setvect(0xBE, intNewIRQ6);
    setvect(0xBF, intNewIRQ7);

    setvect(0x08, intNewIRQ8);
    setvect(0x09, intNewIRQ9);
    setvect(0x0A, intNewIRQ10);
    setvect(0x0B, intNewIRQ11);
    setvect(0x0C, intNewIRQ12);
    setvect(0x0D, intNewIRQ13);
    setvect(0x0E, intNewIRQ14);
    setvect(0x0F, intNewIRQ15);

    //     Init
    //     Master
    value = inp(0x21);      // Запоминаем регистр масок
    outp(0x20, 0x11);       //ICW1 (0b00010001)
                            // bit 0 - ICW4 будет вызвана
                            // bit 1 - использование ведомого контроллера
                            // bit 2 - размер вектора прерываний - 8 байтов
                            // bit 4 - должен быть 1
                            // bits 5-7  - должны быть 0
    outp(0x21, 0xB8);       // адрес вектора прерывания - B8h
    outp(0x21, 0x04);       // ICW3
    outp(0x21, 0x01);       // ICW4
    outp(0x21, value);      // Восстанавливаем регистр масок

    //     Slave
    value = inp(0xA1);  // Запоминаем регистр масок
    outp(0xA0, 0x11);   // ICW1
    outp(0xA1, 0x08);   // адрес вектора прерывания - 08h
    outp(0xA1, 0x02);   // ICW3
    outp(0xA1, 0x01);   // ICW4
    outp(0xa1, value);  // Восстанавливаем регистр масок

    clrscr();
    _dos_keep(0,(_DS-_CS)+(_SP/16)+1); 
}


void binstring(unsigned char temp, char *str)
{
    int i;
    str[8] = 0;
    i=7;

    while(temp)
    {
        str[i]='0'+temp%2;
        temp=temp/2;
        i--;
    }

    for(;i>-1;i--)
        str[i]='0';
}   

void print(char* str, int x, int y, unsigned char color)
{
    int i = 0;
    char far* start = (char far*)0xb8000000;
    start += x+160*y;

    while(str[i] != 0)
    {
        *start = str[i];
        start++;
        *start = color;
        start++;
        i++;
    }               
}

void get_reg()
{
    char str[10];
    int i = 0;
    int isr_master, isr_slave; // Interrupt Service Register - Регистр обслуживаемых прерываний
    int irr_master, irr_slave; // Interrupt Request Register - Регистр запросов на прерывания
    int imr_master, imr_slave; // Interrupt Mask Register  - Регистр масок

    imr_master = inp(0x21);
    imr_slave = inp(0xA1);

    outp(0x20, 0x0A);
    irr_master = inp(0x20);
    outp(0x20, 0x0B);
    isr_master = inp(0x20);

    outp(0xA0,0x0A);
    irr_slave = inp(0xA0);
    outp(0xA0,0x0B);
    isr_slave = inp(0xA0);

    print("Master IC  ISR: ",0, 0, color);
    binstring(isr_master, str);
    print(str, 30 + i, 0, color);


    print("|IRR: ",46, 0, color);
    binstring(irr_master, str);
    print(str, 58, 0, color);   

    print("|MASK: ", 74, 0, color);
    binstring(imr_master, str);
    print(str, 88, 0, color);   

    print("Slave IC   ISR: ", 0, 1, color);
    binstring(isr_slave, str);
    print(str, 30, 1, color);

    print("|IRR: ", 46, 1, color);
    binstring(irr_slave, str);
    print(str, 58, 1, color);   

    print("|MASK: ",74, 1, color);
    binstring(imr_slave, str);
    print(str, 88, 1, color);   
}


void interrupt intNewIRQ0()
{
    get_reg();
    (*intOldIRQ0)();
}

void interrupt intNewIRQ1()
{
    unsigned char value;
    get_reg();
    (*intOldIRQ1)();

    color = 0x40 + colornumber;
    colornumber = (colornumber + 1) % 8;
    value = inp(0x60);

    if (value == 0x01)
    {
        resetint();
        clrscr();
    }   
}

void interrupt intNewIRQ2()
{
    get_reg();
    (*intOldIRQ2)();
}
void interrupt intNewIRQ3()
{
    get_reg();
    (*intOldIRQ3)();
}
void interrupt intNewIRQ4()
{
    get_reg();
    (*intOldIRQ4)();
}
void interrupt intNewIRQ5()
{
    get_reg();
    (*intOldIRQ5)();
}
void interrupt intNewIRQ6()
{
    get_reg();
    (*intOldIRQ6)();
}
void interrupt intNewIRQ7()
{
    get_reg();
    (*intOldIRQ7)();
}
void interrupt intNewIRQ8()
{
    get_reg();
    (*intOldIRQ8)();
}
void interrupt intNewIRQ9()
{
    get_reg();
    (*intOldIRQ9)();
}
void interrupt intNewIRQ10()
{
    get_reg();
    (*intOldIRQ10)();
}
void interrupt intNewIRQ11()
{
    get_reg();
    (*intOldIRQ11)();
}
void interrupt intNewIRQ12()
{
    get_reg();
    (*intOldIRQ12)();
}
void interrupt intNewIRQ13()
{
    get_reg();
    (*intOldIRQ13)();
}
void interrupt intNewIRQ14()
{
    get_reg();
    (*intOldIRQ14)();
}
void interrupt intNewIRQ15()
{
    get_reg();
    (*intOldIRQ15)();
}

void resetint()
{
    disable();

    setvect(0xB8, intOldIRQ0);
    setvect(0xB9, intOldIRQ1);
    setvect(0xBA, intOldIRQ2);
    setvect(0xBB, intOldIRQ3);
    setvect(0xBC, intOldIRQ4);
    setvect(0xBD, intOldIRQ5);
    setvect(0xBE, intOldIRQ6);
    setvect(0xBF, intOldIRQ7);

    setvect(0x08, intOldIRQ8);
    setvect(0x09, intOldIRQ9);
    setvect(0x0A, intOldIRQ10);
    setvect(0x0B, intOldIRQ11);
    setvect(0x0C, intOldIRQ12);
    setvect(0x0D, intOldIRQ13);
    setvect(0x0E, intOldIRQ14);
    setvect(0x0F, intOldIRQ15);

    enable();
}
```

Comment: Это запуск в ОС MS-DOS?

Comment: DOSBox 0.74....

Comment: Наверное, ответ где-то здесь?
https://github.com/mhagdorn/dosbox/blob/master/src/hardware/pic.cpp#L349

Answer (score 0, accepted):

при запуске DOSBox 0.74 появляется вот такое окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И в нём написано, что клавишами ctrl+11 и ctrl+12 можно отрегулировать скорость, у меня стояла максимальная, поэтому я не замечал изменений при нажатии клавиш, установил значение около 30, и теперь можно видеть как происходит взаимодействие регистров

Comment: Откуда дровишки? О каком бите речь? Можете расширить ответ? И что за такая комбинация? *F11*, *F12*?